# Display PHP link

Tags: php

In the following code function:

```
return $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

the output is: */mysqlTilestore/listing.php*

and in the following code function:

```
return $mypage
```

the output is: *page=5*

How to combine the above two codes to return the following:

*/mysqlTilestore/listing.php/?page=5*

I’ve tried the following but I get syntax error:

```
return $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?$mypage;
```

Comment: Suggested reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $mypage;
return $path;
```

Answer (score 0):

`?` needs to be quoted as a string:

```
return $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . $mypage;
```